# XSL outputting to table

Tags: xml, xslt

So I'm trying to learn XSL, and I'm looking at outputting an XML document to a table. I can get 1 line to populate setting  which I know is incorrect, but it's combining records from different players. If I try to select PLAYER or TEAM_NAME I get no records. I can't seem to understand how it should populate each. It's just going right over my head for some reason.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>SEASON</h2>
   <table border="1">
    <tr>
     <th>YEAR</th>
     <th>LEAGUE</th>
     <th>DIVISION</th>
     <th>TEAM_CITY</th>
     <th>TEAM_NAME</th>
     <th>GIVEN_NAME</th>
     <th>SURNAME</th>
     <th>POSITION</th>
     <th>GAMES</th>
     <th>GAMES_STARTED</th>
     <th>WINS</th>
     <th>LOSSES</th>
     <th>SAVES</th>
     <th>COMPLETE_GAMES</th>
     <th>SHUT_OUTS</th>
     <th>ERA</th>
     <th>INNINGS</th>
     <th>EARNED_RUNS</th>
     <th>HIT_BATTER</th>
     <th>WILD_PITCHES</th>
     <th>BALK</th>
     <th>WALKED_BATTER</th>
     <th>STRUCK_OUT_BATTER</th>
     <th>AT_BATS</th>
     <th>RUNS</th>
     <th>HITS</th>
     <th>DOUBLES</th>
     <th>TRIPLES</th>
     <th>"HOME_RUNS" /></th>
     <th>RBI</th>
     <th>STEALS</th>
     <th>CAUGHT_STEALING</th>
     <th>SACRIFICE_HITS</th>
     <th>SACRIFICE_FLIES</th>
     <th>ERRORS</th>
     <th>WALKS</th>
     <th>STRUCK_OUT</th>
     <th>HIT_BY_PITCH</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="/SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/TEAM_NAME">
    <tr>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/YEAR" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/LEAGUE_NAME" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/DIVISION_NAME" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/TEAM_CITY" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/TEAM_NAME" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/GIVEN_NAME" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/SURNAME" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/POSITION" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/GAMES" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/GAMES_STARTED" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/WINS" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/LOSSES" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/SAVES" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/COMPLETE_GAMES" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/SHUT_OUTS" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/ERA" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/INNINGS" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/EARNED_RUNS" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/HIT_BATTER" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/WILD_PITCHES" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/BALK" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/WALKED_BATTER" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/STRUCK_OUT_BATTER" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/AT_BATS" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/RUNS" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/HITS" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/DOUBLES" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/TRIPLES" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/HOME_RUNS" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/RBI" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/STEALS" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/CAUGHT_STEALING" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/SACRIFICE_HITS" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/SACRIFICE_FLIES" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/ERRORS" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/WALKS" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/STRUCK_OUT" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER/HIT_BY_PITCH" /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </table>

 </body>
</html>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<SEASON>
 <YEAR>1998</YEAR>
 
 <LEAGUE>
  <LEAGUE_NAME>National</LEAGUE_NAME>

  <DIVISION>
   <DIVISION_NAME>East</DIVISION_NAME>
  
   <TEAM>
    <TEAM_CITY>Florida</TEAM_CITY>
    <TEAM_NAME>Marlins</TEAM_NAME>
   
    <PLAYER>
     <GIVEN_NAME>Eric</GIVEN_NAME>
     <SURNAME>Ludwick</SURNAME>
     <POSITION>Starting Pitcher</POSITION>
     <GAMES>13</GAMES>
     <GAMES_STARTED>6</GAMES_STARTED>
     <WINS>1</WINS>
     <LOSSES>4</LOSSES>
     <SAVES>0</SAVES>
     <COMPLETE_GAMES>0</COMPLETE_GAMES>
     <SHUT_OUTS>0</SHUT_OUTS>
     <ERA>7.44</ERA>
     <INNINGS>32.2</INNINGS>
     <EARNED_RUNS>31</EARNED_RUNS>
     <HIT_BATTER>27</HIT_BATTER>
     <WILD_PITCHES>0</WILD_PITCHES>
     <BALK>2</BALK>
     <WALKED_BATTER>0</WALKED_BATTER>
     <STRUCK_OUT_BATTER>17</STRUCK_OUT_BATTER>
     </PLAYER>

    <PLAYER>
     <GIVEN_NAME>Brian</GIVEN_NAME>
     <SURNAME>Daubach</SURNAME>
     <POSITION>First Base</POSITION>
     <GAMES>10</GAMES>
     <GAMES_STARTED>3</GAMES_STARTED>
     <AT_BATS>15</AT_BATS>
     <RUNS>0</RUNS>
     <HITS>3</HITS>
     <DOUBLES>1</DOUBLES>
     <TRIPLES>0</TRIPLES>
     <HOME_RUNS>0</HOME_RUNS>
     <RBI>3</RBI>
     <STEALS>0</STEALS>
     <CAUGHT_STEALING>0</CAUGHT_STEALING>
     <SACRIFICE_HITS>0</SACRIFICE_HITS>
     <SACRIFICE_FLIES>0</SACRIFICE_FLIES>
     <ERRORS>0</ERRORS>
     <WALKS>1</WALKS>
     <STRUCK_OUT>5</STRUCK_OUT>
     <HIT_BY_PITCH>1</HIT_BY_PITCH>
    </PLAYER>
   </TEAM>

   <TEAM>
    <TEAM_CITY>Montreal</TEAM_CITY>
    <TEAM_NAME>Expos</TEAM_NAME>
   </TEAM>

   <TEAM>
    <TEAM_CITY>New York</TEAM_CITY>
    <TEAM_NAME>Mets</TEAM_NAME>
   </TEAM>

   <TEAM>
    <TEAM_CITY>Philadelphia</TEAM_CITY>
    <TEAM_NAME>Phillies</TEAM_NAME>
   </TEAM>
  </DIVISION>
  
  <DIVISION>
   <DIVISION_NAME>Central</DIVISION_NAME>
   <TEAM>
    <TEAM_CITY>Chicago</TEAM_CITY>
    <TEAM_NAME>Cubs</TEAM_NAME>
   </TEAM>
  </DIVISION>

  <DIVISION>
   <DIVISION_NAME>West</DIVISION_NAME>
   <TEAM>
    <TEAM_CITY>Arizona</TEAM_CITY>
    <TEAM_NAME>Diamondbacks</TEAM_NAME>
   </TEAM>
  </DIVISION>
 </LEAGUE>

 <LEAGUE>
  <LEAGUE_NAME>American</LEAGUE_NAME>
 
  <DIVISION>
   <DIVISION_NAME>East</DIVISION_NAME>
   <TEAM>
    <TEAM_CITY>Baltimore</TEAM_CITY>
    <TEAM_NAME>Orioles</TEAM_NAME>
   </TEAM>
  </DIVISION>

  <DIVISION>
   <DIVISION_NAME>Central</DIVISION_NAME>
   <TEAM>
    <TEAM_CITY>Chicago</TEAM_CITY>
    <TEAM_NAME>White Sox</TEAM_NAME>
   </TEAM>
  </DIVISION>

  <DIVISION>
   <DIVISION_NAME>West</DIVISION_NAME>
   <TEAM>
    <TEAM_CITY>Anaheim</TEAM_CITY>
    <TEAM_NAME>Angels</TEAM_NAME>
   </TEAM>
  </DIVISION>
 </LEAGUE>
</SEASON>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (as it seems) you want each player to occupy a row, then you need to create a row for each player -  and get the season, league, division and team data from the corresponding ancestor nodes.

Try this minimized example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>SEASON</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>YEAR</th>
                    <th>LEAGUE</th>
                    <th>DIVISION</th>
                    <th>TEAM_CITY</th>
                    <th>TEAM_NAME</th>
                    <th>GIVEN_NAME</th>
                    <th>SURNAME</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::SEASON/YEAR" /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::LEAGUE/LEAGUE_NAME" /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::DIVISION/DIVISION_NAME" /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="../TEAM_CITY" /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="../TEAM_NAME" /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="GIVEN_NAME" /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="SURNAME" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, the (rendered) result will be:

[image]

Comment: Awesome thank you! That worked, and the ancestor bit was something I hadn't seen when I was searching on Google, so thank you. I was able to format it in a few different ways based on what you put so I think I get it a bit better now.